# Pulp Linear optimization with objective function as Matrix multiplication

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have an objective function that finds standard deviation using var-covariance matrix and weighted vector.

```
In [388]: equal_weights
Out[388]: 
array([ 3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,
    3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,
    3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,
    3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,
    3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857,
    3.57142857,  3.57142857,  3.57142857])
```

And I have var-cov matrix of shape 28,28

```
var_cov_matrix
Out[389]: 
array([[  6.71849405e-04,   1.07026673e-04,   6.79182814e-04,
      5.92496081e-04,   6.76905450e-04,   5.68079259e-04,
      2.22977933e-04,   6.27305383e-04,   1.93215258e-04,
      7.58978339e-04,   6.04280523e-04,   6.76028095e-04,
      5.56815379e-04,   7.24121343e-04,   1.29104023e-04,
      5.65809917e-04,   2.21988437e-04,   7.96973235e-05,
      6.22684153e-04,   7.24716154e-04,   7.34006960e-04,
      8.06120887e-04,   7.00056878e-04,   6.61041132e-04,
      1.43439814e-04,   2.27692364e-04,   4.44174103e-04,
      4.52772521e-04],
   [  1.07026673e-04,......]]
```

I have to find optimized weights by running the pulp optimizer. The objective function is,

```
math.sqrt((eq_wt_vector.transpose() @ var_cov_matrix) @ eq_wt_vector)
```

The objective is to minimize the value generated by the above function with constraint,

```
sum(equal_weights) - 1 == 0
```

I went through a lot of examples and solutions are available for linear equations. A solution for this particular problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a quadratic program, not a linear program. Use, say, CVXPY instead of PuLP.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/27076/20417).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rodrigo de Azevedo for the tip. 
Yes, I was able to solve the problem using cvxpy package. There are various conditions to use the cvxpy library and are as follows,

1. The objective function to minimize or maximize should follow Disciplined Convex Programming (DCP) [look here](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/dcp/)
2. Care should be taken if the problem is a maximization or minimization one. I had a sqrt() method to find the standard deviation, which was not a DCP as well as made my problem a maximization one.

The solution is as follows,

Obj function:

```
(eq_wt_vector.transpose() @ var_cov_matrix) @ eq_wt_vector
```

which is represented in DCP as

```
Minimize(quad_form(a, b))
```

Where quad(a,b) = a.T * b * a

Solution:

```
from cvxpy import Variable,Problem,Minimize,sum_entries,quad_form
a = Variable(var_cov_matrix.shape[0]) #vector of column length = matrix length
b = np.matrix(var_cov_matrix)
objective = Minimize(quad_form(a, b))
constraints = [sum_entries(a) == 100,  0<=a, a<=100] #constraints for vector - sum of elements = 100, lies between 0,100
prob = Problem(objective, constraints)

optimized_deviation = prob.solve()
```